# Cannot assign to an element of an initonly array?

Tags: c++-cli

It seems commonly thought that C++/CLI's `initonly` is the equivalent of C#'s `readonly` keyword. However, the following:

```
ref class C { 
    C();
    void Method();
    initonly array<int>^ m_array;
};

C::C() {
    m_array = gcnew array<int>(10);
}

void C::Method() {
    m_array[0] = 5; // Fails with C3893
}
```

The full error is `"'C::m_array': l-value use of initonly data member is only allowed in an instance constructor of class 'C'"`.

The error message seems strange as I'm not using m_array as the target of an assignment, this is the equivalent of writing

```
m_array->SetValue(5, 0);
```

which incidentally compiles fine and does the same thing.

Is this bugged in C++/CLI or by design? By the way, is there any performance penalty to using `Array::SetValue` vs using the accessor?

A similar (but not identical) case was reported and apparently filed as a bug for VS2008: http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/847520-initonly-but-not-bug-vc-2008-clr . I'm using Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's a bug.  It's enforcing something which is not implied by the .NET type system, and the enforcement is ineffective.

But don't use `Array::SetValue`, which involves boxing and is not type safe.  You can just do:

```
auto array = m_array; // another handle to same array
array[0] = 5;
```